# Swift debug console autocomplete

Tags: xcode, swift

Is it just me or is everyone not able to use autocomplete inside Xcode's console when debugging Swift code? This seems to be the case for me with the latest Xcode 7.0.1, and all other previous Xcode versions for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not any single mention of the word "swift" on the lldb website, presumably support for swift autocompletion does not exist. And it's true for me as well since Xcode6.